# Help for rating system calculation formula

Tags: generating-functions

I am trying to solve a "Trickle down" Rating Formula.

The interaction is between a Seller, a Service, Participants in the Service and several Buyers of the Service.
The rating is from 1 to 5 where 5 is the top rating.
The Seller and Participants Can not Rate on the Service.

The Service Rating is done by the Buyers and is calculated by Weighted average Plus the Sellers and Participants Rating:
What formula should I use?
Rating=(1*N1+2*N2+3*N3+4*N4+5*N5)/TotalN

The Seller and Participants rating is only based on the rating of the previous Services and the total of all Services created:
What formula should I use?

Thank you in advance for any help.
Vasco

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, I will try to be more clear :